# Django - Page not found (404) urls.py

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

problem:

> Page not found (404)
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/category/coding/
> Raised by:  blogapp.views.BlogDetailView

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls.conf import path
from blogapp.views import BlogDetailView, BlogListView,searchposts,CatListView
from . import views

app_name = "blogapp"
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.BlogListView, name="blogs"),
path('home/search/', views.searchposts, name= "searchposts"),
path('home/category/<slug:_id>/', views.BlogDetailView, name="blog"),
path('home/category/<category>/', views.CatListView.as_view(), name="category"),
]
```

if i reverse this two

```
path('home/category/<slug:_id>/', views.BlogDetailView, name="blog"),  
   path('home/category/<category>/', views.CatListView.as_view(), name="category"),
```

it shows the html of the **category** , and the path of *'path('home/category/slug:_id/', views.BlogDetailView, name="blog"),'* is not showing , **vice versa**

here is the html of **navbar**

```
      {% for category in category_list %}
      {% if forloop.counter < 4 %}
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="home/category/{{category.name}}">{{ category.name|title }}</a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
```

**html that i want to render**

```
{% extends "_layouts/base.html" %}

{% block css %}
{{block.super}}

{% endblock css %}

{% block page_title %}Insert_your_name_here{% endblock %}

{% load static %} <!-- load the image -->
{% block maincontent %}
<!-- Banner -->
{% block banner %}
{% load static %}
{% include "layout/category_banner.html" %}
{% endblock %}
<!-- Banner Here -->

!-- This is the main template -->
<section class="blog-posts grid-system">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-8">
    <div class="all-blog-posts">
      <div class="row">
       {% block categories-main %}
       {% include "layout/category.html" %}
       {% endblock %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% block sidebars %}
{% load static %}
{% include "layout/Sidebars.html" %}
{% endblock %}
</div>
</div>
</section>
{% endblock %}
```

here is my **views.py**

```
def BlogDetailView(request,_id):
try:
    category_list = Category.objects.exclude(name='default')
    dataset = BlogModel.newmanager.all()
    data = BlogModel.newmanager.get(slug =_id)
    comments = CommentModel.objects.filter(blog = data, status=True)
except BlogModel.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404('Data does not exist')
 
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        Comment = CommentModel(your_name= form.cleaned_data['your_name'],
        comment = form.cleaned_data['comment'],
        blog=data)
        Comment.save()
        return redirect(f'/home/category/{_id}')
else:
    form = CommentForm()

context = {
        'data':data,
        'form':form,
        'comments':comments,
        'dataset': dataset,
        "category_list": category_list,
    }
return render(request,'layout/post-details-main.html',context)


def searchposts(request):
dataset = BlogModel.newmanager.all()
if request.method == 'GET':
    query= request.GET.get('q')

    submitbutton= request.GET.get('submit')

    if query is not None:
        lookups= Q(blog_title__icontains=query) | Q(blog__icontains=query)

        results= BlogModel.objects.filter(lookups).distinct()

        context={'results': results,
                 'submitbutton': submitbutton,
                 'dataset': dataset,
                }

        return render(request, 'layout/search-main.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'layout/search-main.html')

else:
    return render(request, 'layout/search-main.html')

class CatListView(ListView):
template_name = 'layout/category-main.html'
context_object_name = 'catlist'

def get_queryset(self):
    content = {
        'cat' : self.kwargs['category'],
        'posts' : 
 BlogModel.objects.filter(category__name=self.kwargs['category']).filter(status='published') 
    } 
    return content

def category_list(request):
category_list = Category.objects.exclude(name='default')
context = {
    "category_list": category_list,
}
return context
```

it says that the problem is raised by **blogapp.views.BlogDetailView** so i added this to my BlogDetailView render it to my main html :

```
category_list = Category.objects.exclude(name='default')
context = {
    "category_list": category_list,
}
```

i think the problem is the link? of my navbar or the BlogDetailView?, What is the problem of this?

Comment: Using bloth `slug` and `str` makes not much sense, since simple strings can act both as a slug and string, only strings with punctuations, diacritics, etc., the slug does not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case is solved i using both str and slug, so my **category** does not match to my _id, need to match those two

```
path('home/category/<slug:category>/', views.CatListView.as_view(), name="category"),
path('home/category/<slug:_id>/', views.BlogDetailView, name="blog")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept it as string

Try like this:

```
path('home/category/<str:category>/', views.CatListView.as_view(), name="category"),
```

Comment: it says KeyError at /home/category/coding/
'category'

Comment: but if i remove the  'cat' : self.kwargs['category'] in my func 'get_queryset' it works fine but i want to render the title of my categories

Comment: KeyError at /home/category/coding/
'category'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/category/coding/
Django Version: 2.2.24
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value: 
'category'
Exception Location: /mnt/d/django_main/project/src/blogapp/views.py in get_queryset, line 82